# What is the difference between List[int] and list[int] in python 3.9+?

Tags: python, python-typing

When defining a function in python and specifying the types of the arguments, what is the difference between using this syntax:

```
from typing import List

def fun(arg: List[int]):
    ...
```

and using this:

```
def fun(arg: list[int]):
    ...
```

It seems that the first option is more used but i like the second one better.
Thank you!

Comment: `List` was first defined and later Python version allowed the use of `list` without the `typing` import